# Lining up text in javafx label

Tags: java, javafx, string-formatting

I have a JavaFX application where I am updating 10 labels in a vbox.  Below is the code that updates the labels:

```
String output = String.format("%-30s: %d", name, score);
labelArr[i].setText(output);
```

I would like the names to be aligned and the scores to be aligned, but here is what I am getting

[image: not aligned textfields]

*Excuse the dummy values

Answer (score 2):

You could put the labels inside of a `GridPane` with two colums.

```
GridPane gp = new GridPane();
```

Answer (score -1):

The simplest solution is using Monospace font:

```
label.setFont(new Font("Monospace", 12));
```